# Element Plus Datepicker closes Veutify 3 dialog on change

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3, element-plus, v-dialog, el-date-picker

As can be seen in the codepen below, whenever I select a date in the Element+  `el-date-picker`, the `v-dialog` component closes.

[Veutify 3 & Element+ Codepen](https://codepen.io/SL_SL/pen/ExevaLy?editors=1111)

Excpected behaviour would be to select the date and the dialog should stay opened.

I have tried using `persistent` keyword on the `v-dialog`, but this gives a glichty feel to it, as it seems the dialog still wants to be closed, but prevents it from happening.

Does anybody know why the dialog is closed whenever a date in the Element component is selected?

How can this be prevented?

Answer (score -1):

You can prevent closing using [Persistent](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs/#persistent).

```
 <v-dialog v-model="dialog" activator="parent" persistent>
```

Here is the updated [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tolbxela/pen/XWPabMg)

By the way, mixing of different frameworks could be problematic and  cause some incompatibility problems.

Comment: I know thats exactly what I've already tried... I still want to be able to close the modal when I click outside of it, so using persistent won`t do the trick

Comment: I believe this is exactly what happens here. Since Element+ DatePicker is outside the v-dialog, the click to the DatePicker Date fires a `click outside` for the v-dialog and closes it. So, I am not sure if it possible to achieve the behavior you want. You could make a workaround with a save/close button